# Jenkins doesn't build the up-to-date source code from Gitlab

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I created a GitLab project and pushed codes to the repository, and managed to link it to my Jenkins server. After clicking `build` in Jenkins, it gave me the blue light.

But, after pushing changes to the repo and clicking the `build` button again in Jenkins, I still see the blue light but the build has no changes.

I believe that this problem is very closely related to the project configuration in Jenkins. How can I make Jenkins build with the up-to-date source code from the repo?

If you need more information on the build configuration, please let me know.

Here's the current version info.

(1) Jenkins: 2.60.1 (the WAR file)

(2) GitLab: GitLab CE 9.2.6

(3) Jenkins GitLab plugin: 1.4.5

(4) Jenkins Git plugin: 3.1

Comment: it would be a good start to add precise version numbers for your setup for (a) Jenkins, (b) Jenkins git plugin, (c) git/gitlab/github on the server side.

Comment: I know, this is a bit of a lame question, but do you build the correct git branch?

Comment: @MWiesner I just uploaded the version info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have no idea how it works, but somehow I found the answer. It was the `Refspec` that was causing the problem, so I went to `Jenkins -> My project -> configuration -> source code management -> Git -> Repositories -> Advanced` and changed the `Refspec` value into `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/merge-requests/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/merge-requests/*`, and now it's reflecting the up-to-date source code to build.